# Need comprehensive list of all native objects

Tags: javascript

I'm getting exactly what I want when I do this `console.dir(this)` in Chrome.
Is there a way to get that into an array some how?
So I've tried to do something like this to get started:

```
for(var o in console.dir(this)) {
     console.log(o);
}
```

All I get is "undefined" and it prints the list into the console again.
I really just need a name list of all Native Javascript Objects and their respective methods and attributes without the hassle of manually creating and maintaining a monstrous list. Ideally the solution would be a dynamically created array of everything; either flat or multidimensional array so I can iterate through it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're making it too hard: it's already in a dictionary, because everything in Javascript is already a dictionary.

Just open the javascript console and type `this`, and you get an object that expands to

```
> this
DOMWindow
Infinity: Infinity
Array: function Array() { [native code] }
Attr: function Attr() { [native code] }
Audio: [object Function]
BeforeLoadEvent: function BeforeLoadEvent() { [native code] }
Blob: function Blob() { [native code] }
BlobBuilder: function BlobBuilder() { [native code] }
Boolean: function Boolean() { [native code] }
CDATASection: function CDATASection() { [native code] }
CSSCharsetRule: function CSSCharsetRule() { [native code] }
```

(truncated because you can see it yourself.)  If you want a particular element of it, just address it: it's a `DOMWindow` object, it has an element `Array`, which has an element `prototype`, which contains all the method functions.

Comment: Nah, just the opposite -- as I say, you're making it too hard.  The thing you're presented with is already an array.