# What native constructors are not accessible through the global object?

Tags: javascript, native-code

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955984/need-comprehensive-list-of-all-native-objects) it is recommended in order get all native objects to use the global object. However the answer is incomplete as there are other native objects which are not accessible through the global object.

I know of at least one-- `Arguments` which has no reference from the global object. What other constructors are not accessible through the global object?

This question is not limited to browsers, but could include Node as well.

Comment: What is the one that you know of?

Comment: I stated it in my question -- `Arguments` (that is the Arguments constructor). Let me format it a little better so that is more obvious

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: I never heard about an `Arguments` constructor. Isn't `arguments` an instance of `Object`?

Comment: `Arguments` is in fact a native type. You can test it with the following:

    var args = (function () {return arguments})();
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(args));

You will have `[object Arguments]` printed to the console.

Comment: @Eli ALthough your code does output what you say, it doesn't mean there's an `Arguments` constructor. See [section 10.6 of the language specification](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6). So I don't know what would be a valid answer to your question. Maybe "native objects are all accessible through the global object, and may be inspected with [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)".

Comment: +1. @bfavaretto You are correct. Not being familiar with the language specification I assumed if an object had a unique class (as represented in Object.prototype.toString.call) it was a native type. Looks like I need to get more familiar with the language spec. If anyone else would like proof of what @bfavaretto has said, try the following: `var args = (function () {
    return arguments;
})();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(args) === Object.getPrototypeOf({}));
console.log(args.constructor === ({}).constructor);`

Comment: @bfavaretto If you put your comment in the form of an answer I will select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you list all objects referenced on the global object, that will include [native objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6) (core language objects) and [host objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.8) (supplied by the host environment; in a browser, all the DOM stuff, and more). That's all we can use on our code.

There is no `Arguments` constructor on that list. There could be one, but there isn't:

> The arguments object is created by calling the abstract operation CreateArgumentsObject
>   [ECMAScript 5.1, Section 10.6](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6)

Roughly, that operation creates a regular `Object` (standard constructor, standard prototype), extends it with some extra properties like `length`, and sets its `[[Class]]` internal property to `"Arguments"`. That's why `arguments.toString()` is `[object Arguments]`.